# Classic ASP global.asa Performance

Tags: iis, asp-classic

I am working on an old classic asp app which includes type libraries in an include file that is included at the top of every page:

```
<%
Session.LCID = 1033 'en-US
Session.CodePage = 65001

Response.LCID = 1033 'en-US
Response.charset ="utf-8"
%>
<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" UUID="00000205-0000-0010-8000-00AA006D2EA4" NAME="ADODB Type Library" -->
<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" UUID="420B2830-E718-11CF-893D-00A0C9054228" NAME="Microsoft Scripting Runtime" -->
<!--METADATA TYPE="typelib" UUID="CD000000-8B95-11D1-82DB-00C04FB1625D" NAME="CDO for Windows 2000 Library" -->
<!--METADATA TYPE="TypeLib" UUID="94A0E92D-43C0-494E-AC29-FD45948A5221" NAME="Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) Automation Layer" -->
<%
```

I've read that type libraries can be included in a global.asa file. I tried it and it does work fine.

My question is - which is the more efficient place (performance wise) to include those, and why?

Comment: It seems fairly obvious to me, but still this is just opinion *(which doesn't make this question a very good fit for [so])*. If you include the typelibs in each page they are needed that is a lot of references *(across concurrent connections)* where as `global.asa` is loaded once at application start. Personally if I'm using the same typelibs in a lot of page [tag:adodb] for example then I use `global.asa` otherwise I tend to use on a page by page basis.

Comment: After reading [my own advice](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37681442/classic-asp-global-asa-performance#comment62840714_37681442) I'd probably go back and add them all into `global.asa` rather then loading per page regardless of where they are used. Also good article on the subject [Using METADATA to Import DLL Constants](http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/webtech/110199-1.shtml) - *"supposedly increases performance. At least according to Microsoft"*

Comment: *Side-note:* Why would you set `Session.LCID = 1033` and `Session.CodePage = 65001` in every page?

Comment: I was leaning toward `global.asa` for the same reasoning you had, but couldn't find anything concrete to back up my decision, hence posting the question.  And RE: the `Session.*` settings, you are right, they don't belong there. Will be moving those to `Session_onStart`

Comment: To be honest, Classic ASP is over 20 years ago finding a definative answer is going to be tough. But my experience so far has been use the `global.asa` whenever possible, this also goes for setting `Session` level values like `CodePage` and `LCID` too.